# Shortest way to check if a word in contained within another word?

Tags: regex, r

What is the shortest way to find out if a word is a subset of another word, keeping the order intact ?

Example: I have two words:

```
word1 <- "grade", 
word2 <- "upgradeable"
word1 %in% word2    # FALSE
```

Is there a function that would return TRUE for the above requirement ?

Answer (score 4):

```
word1 <- "grade"; word2 <- "upgradeable"
grep(word1, word2)
## [1] 1
grepl(word1, word2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Read up on regular expression:

```
?regex
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [regexpr](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/regexpr), which will also give you the position and length of the matched string:

```
> regexpr('grade', 'upgradeable')
[1] 3
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 5
```

The first returned value is TRUE `[1]` starting at position `3`; the second returned value is TRUE `[1]` with a length of `5`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
grepl('grade', 'upgradeable')
# [1] TRUE
```